# MVP.XSL: func:function

Tags: xslt, exslt

I'm using Mvp.Xsl.dll implementation of EXSLT. I'm having hard time to create a custom function and call it from XPath. Is this possible? Can you provide one very simple example?
Thanks a lot,
Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Exslt.Net doesn't implement the EXSLT `<func:function>` extension element.**

I would strongly recommend to start using XSLT 2.0 and its `<xsl:function>` instruction.

Comment: I'm restricted to .NET framework and Mvp.Xml library (customer requirement). If there was some *free .NET implementation* of XSLT 2.0, they would agree on using it, but most likely there is none.

Comment: @Peter: Saxon.NET for ver. 9.1.07 or before is free. XQSharp is free for personal use.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions. I proposed using both of above plus one more option (Altova processor). I guess any of these will be better then using XSLT 1.0, because I need to do a lot of data manipulation, calculations etc. Unfortunately the customer insists on using Microsoft only technologies. Linq to xml is not an option, as I need something that does not need compilation (often changes, need to change something quickly and other reasons).

Comment: @Peter: Maybe the function you need can have an XSLT only implementation. Why don't you start asking from there?